# Where can I download Southern California Interstate Highway System in a Shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, data, united-states, transportation

Does anybody know where I can download the Interstate highway system (as a shapefile) for Southern California (the area around San Diego in particular)?

Comment: If you're focusing on San Diego, you might want to check out the San Diego Association of Governments website. They have some good data: http://www.sandag.org

Answer (score 3):

Go to https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2012/main and select Roads from the layer.  Then you can select either all primary and secondary roads for the state, or you can get all the roads on a county by county basis.

Comment: I've already got ALL the roads for San Diego County (161,000 +)! I need JUST the interstates (to differentiate from a residential street).

Comment: You could download the California Primary & Secondary roads shapefile (a 13MB download) and clip them with the San Diego County boundary.  If your existing layer is based on TIGER you could also look in your attribute table and pull records with S1100 or S1200 in the MTFCC field.

Comment: This is the answer! I'm using this in my own program (that I wrote) and it only took a few seconds to clip the data to San Diego County... thanks!

Comment: Awesome!  Glad to help!  Out of curiosity, what language are you using?  Which libraries?

Comment: I'm writing in C# ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF.

Answer (score 2):

I've only done a quick search but there's one for the whole of the USA here:

http://www.nws.noaa.gov/geodata/catalog/transportation/html/interst.htm

Comment: Yes, that's the ENTIRE interstate (>600 kb)! I need JUST the interstates in San Diego county (to differentiate from the residential roads and alleys which I already have as a shapefile).

Comment: Can you not filter to get only the ones that interest you then?
"He who can do more can do less"

Comment: I'm not using ARCGIS Desktop Explorer; I'm writing my own code. I'm actually 'clipping' the data to a rectangle (in this case downtown San Diego).